# ElasticSearch returning no result when search by a particular field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I've docs with two fields: `id` and `code`. `code` is used as main key (`_id`) too. When I seek by `id` I can get the results but if I seek by `code` nothing is returned. This was working but with no reason or changes stopped works.

ElasticSearch version: 7.1

Doc:

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "code": "AAAEEXXX",
  "name": "Sample name"
}
```

Search query by `id` works.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "term": {
                    "id": 123
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result from `id` query:

```
{
    "took": 2,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 1,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "test-index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "AAAEEXXX",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "id": 123,
                    "code": "AAAEEXXX",
                    "name": "Sample name"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**BUT**, if I search by `code` not works.

Query by code:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "term": {
                    "code": "AAAEEXXX"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result from `code` query:

```
{
    "took": 2,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 0,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your mapping  of index?

Comment: "code": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.keyword` mapping for an exact match like so:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "term": {
                    "code.keyword": "AAAEEXXX"   <--
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```